# Attributes initialization Java

Tags: java, constructor

I was collecting design paterns for a personal cheat sheet and I found a, at least for me, strange piece of code at *Head First Design Patterns (By Eric Freeman, Elisabeth Robson, Bert Bates, Kathy Sierra)*.

I don't think I am allowed to post here the piece of code exactly at is written in the book but I will reproduce the code that shocked me:

Assuming we have previously deffined the class `A` with a public method runSomeCode(), then we have class B as follows:

```
public class B {

    A a;
    A b;
    A x = a;

    public B() {
        a = new A();
        b = new A();
    }

    public void testB()
    {
        x.runSomeCode();
    }    
}
```

My first impression looking at this code is that any call to a B instance testB method should throw a `NullPointerException` but I couldn't imagine they would had published such a mistake.

If the book is right then I understand that

```
x = a;
```

must be done at the end of B constructor execution but I am still surprised by this sintaxis and my questions are:

- Am I wrong?
- Has Java always behaved like this?
- In that case (I personally consider this a little bit confusing): Is it likely to be removed in future Java versions?
- Would you try to avoid it?

**EDIT** THis is the book example:

[image]

The case I am concerned about is when numberGumballs = 0;

**EDIT II**

I think I know what happened with the example.

In the book, the referenced classes are **NOT** declared static but few minutes ago I thought it could compile if A was static. So, maybe, the book authors got the code from a larger project where static classes were being used. So I tried this and, this time, it does work but the example seems to continue being wrong and the following code doesn't make any sense concerning [State pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern).

```
public class B {

    public static class Base {
        public static void runSomeCode() { System.out.println("Base!"); }
    }

    public static class A extends Base {
        public static void runSomeCode() { System.out.println("A!"); }
   }; 

    A a;
    A b;
    A x = a;

    public B() {
        a = new A();
        b = new A();
    }

    public void testB()
    {
        x.runSomeCode();
    }    
}
```

**Yet Another Edit**

It seems I have not been the first one to notice this problem in the book example,
at [O'Reilly site errata section, under unconfirmed erratas sub-section](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errataunconfirmed.csp?isbn=9780596007126) you can find:

[image]

Comment: It does definitely throw an NPE, you can (actually) try it.

Comment: @m0skit0 You're right I tested the case late at night and I may had done something different. However, the example at the book is like that so the book its wrong or I am blind/idiot

Comment: The example in the book is wrong, happens sometimes ;)

Comment: I agree. It seems that you've found an error in the book's code

Comment: Now the book writers will pay a lot of cash to remove this question as it trashes their reputation as computer scientists. Brilliantly done, Sir!

Comment: @darijan It's a great book I think it could never be judged by a silly  insignificant bug which affects just one case (numberGumballs = 0) I am sure the example is not centered on.

Comment: It's a joke, the book is awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. I believe you are wrong, according to the [Java 8 Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) field initializers are executed *before* the constructor body.
2. I believe it has, but don't feel like going through the specification for every version. I'm not aware of any changes though.
3. I doubt it, seeing how it's part of the specification and would break compatibility if they changed it. But
4. In this case the code can easily be changed over to explicitly stating the order of initialization by moving the assignment to `x` into the constructor. Having it as a field initializer has no benefits that would be obvious to me.

What's supposed to be the point of this "pattern"? You just end up with two references where one would have done...why not just use `a` instead?

Answer (score 1):

> Am I wrong?

In-place variable initialization works before initialization in constructor, in the same order as variable defined in code.

> Has Java always behaved like this?

Yes.

> In that case (I personally consider this a little bit confusing): Is
>   it likely to be removed in future Java versions?

No, Java is backward compatible language, this is basic and will not be changed.

> Would you try to avoid it?

If you want in-place initialization, make sure that it's independent of initializing of other variables. Otherwise initialize it in the constructor. Don't make complex in-place initialization.

Comment: I already stated in the question that as far as I knew it dind't make sense. On the other hand I tested it late at night and I think I might have done something different, I'll try to reproduce it however.

Answer (score 1):

When you first create an object of type B, the fields that have any initializations are initialized first. So, `A x = a;` is executed first, even before the code in the constructor is executed which sets the value of x to null, since a has not been instantiated and is just a null reference of type A. After this, the following code is executed which creates the two objects.

```
public B() {
    a = new A();
    b = new A();
}
```

x is still null at this point. So when you try to execute a method in A class using x, it will throw a null pointer exception.

Comment: I already stated in the question that as far as I knew it dind't make sense. On the other hand I tested it late at night and I think I might have done something different, I'll try to reproduce it however.